# Branes in Closed Bosonic String Theory

Tags: string-theory, branes

I've seen in [these lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFxDQ1_sulk-74ZEwVDatDdCV5LfsVTe2) by Freddy Cachazo that type II-A/B superstring theory has to contain D-branes and open strings non-perturbatively, even though it appears to only contain closed strings in the perturbation theory. I've also read [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/32235/why-are-there-no-branes-in-heterotic-string-theory?show=32247#a32247) that heterotic superstring theory might also contain p-branes.

Is it known whether closed bosonic string theory contains branes, i.e. objects different from the fundamental string, even if they don't appear perturbatively, as in the type II A/B superstring case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the bosonic string doesn't make sense non-perturbatively so the question of whether it contains non-perturbative objects is meaningless to begin with.

Comment: (That being said, half of the heterotic string is the bosonic string. And heterotic does not contain D-branes so...)

Comment: But it does contain NS5-branes...

Comment: Doesn't make sense non-perturbatively? Is this to do with the existence of the tachyon, or something else?

Comment: Yes to Mitchell and Yes to OP.